# FlipFlop outputs half voltage SN74HC74D

Tags: integrated-circuit, flipflop, troubleshooting

I first did a simulation of a simple circuit with the IC SN74HC74D and it outputs 5V, please see attached image.
I made a circuit and ordered a PCB. When soldered it only outputs 2.5V(Pin ~Q_2). I cannot figure out the reason.. Is the simulation faulty?
[image]

Comment: is that with a squarewave input clock using a meter? is it floating? load it? or Q and Qbar shorted together

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your output is oscillating between 0 and 5 volts to cause an average voltage reading of 2.5 volts. The long leads you have to your switch (?) in your diagram are probably picking up enough noise to cause the oscillation. Try tying a 10k ohm resistor between pin 3 and ground right on your circuit board.

In general, you should tie together all other unused inputs and connect these to a 10k resistor to ground to keep noise out of the circuit.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! My bad, but there is a 10k ohm resistor to ground on GPIO04, but isnt shown in the circuit above.. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Note that all other unused inputs, on the entire chip, must also be tied low as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough info, let me guess

You use HC chip, but feed it with 3.3 V digital signal which is outside of the HC logic level definition. In order for chip to accept 3.3 V signal you need either LS type or HCT type. As Glenn said chip oscillates at its output, but because it can not identify logical level on its CLK input.

Do simple test. Set CLK input to +5 V or to GND (and of course disconnect it from GPIO before making this test). You will see chip's output will get stable with either 5 V or 0 V output.

Please also

- ensure chip is powered at 5 V (voltage between pins 14 and 7 of the chip);
- double-check wiring;
- finally, try another chip.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! According to the datasheet I thought it should be able to use 3.3V.. I tried 5V but the same happened. I tried to use the large non-pcb SN74HC74N on a breadboard (should be the same, right?). It worked when I measured the output with above wiring, but when I hooked up a relay (80mA) it didnt output correctly anymore.. Is it not possible to connect a relay directly to something? Do I need to use a transistor afterwards?

Comment: Most probably relay will draw current exceeding maximal value for HC output. You will need transistor to drive the relay.

Answer (score 1):

And just as another possible problem, you have left the unused inputs (pins 10,11,12,13)  floating. This is an absolute no-no with CMOS. The other 2 answers are both spot on, and are more likely the problem, but this remains a possibility. Just because the floating pins are not directly part of the flip-flop which you are using does not mean they are completely isolated. They are, after all, part of the same chip. Trust me on this - I've seen it happen, and it took a whole lot of sweat and tears to track it down, since "obviously it can't be a problem".

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tested to not have them floating and hooked them up to GND via a 10k ohm resistor, same issue though. Please see my replay to Anonumous above.
Very good to know though for the future!

Comment: @Martik - 10ik is not a horrible choice, but for inputs which will not be used, tying directly to ground or Vcc is a better idea. And Anonymous is correct - a 74HC74 will not directly drive a relay.